# PostgreSQL: Run function many times with different arguments (of same type)

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that takes a parameter `uid` and returns a table. I'd like to add **call this function multiple times with different arguments** (but of the same type, `VARCHAR(11)`) and put those **results in a temporary table** (so I can pull a CSV out of it).

My function does not seem to be able to loop through it properly

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS programs_to_analyze;

CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS programs_to_analyze (
  uid VARCHAR(11)
);

INSERT INTO programs_to_analyze(uid)
VALUES ('lUGqq3na2wn');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction()
  RETURNS TABLE(identifier VARCHAR(11)) AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  program programs_to_analyze%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  FOR program IN
    SELECT uid
    FROM programs_to_analyze
  LOOP
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * from some_query(program);
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

When running `select * from myfunction();` I receive 0 rows (expected: 18 rows as tested).

How can I put those results into one table when declaring multiple rows in `programs_to_analyze`?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `select q.* from programs_to_analyze p, some_query(p.uid);`

Comment: `p.uid` is actually used to construct some within `some_query` but I left that out for the sake of readablity

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean with that. You need to show us the complete code and possible some sample data and the output based on that

Comment: It won't work as you wish because whenever you use `RETURN` it always 'comes out' of the PL.. You have to insert your query into a record variable or a temporal table (probably it will be best a temporal table for your case). Then, when you use `RETURN` you have to return the whole thing. Example: `RETURN variable`